# Align Image with text CSS

Tags: html, css, image, web, alignment

I can't understand why this text won't line up with the middle of an image. Check the screenshots below, one highlighted, one not:

[image]
[image: highlight]

I want the word Australia to line up in the middle of the image (aligned with the arrow). As you see from the highlight it isn't the height of the image that is the problem.

I have tried vertical-align:middle which helps but as you can see it is not perfect!

Suggestions appreciated!

Comment: Place the text in a div and apply padding-top so you get the desired position.

Comment: Setting the line-height for the text div to the same height as the image can sometimes be helpful with this. It would be easier to tell what's going on if you post some code, though...

Comment: I would go with line-height rather than padding if possible as well

Comment: I suggest you put you sample code in here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this is a link, use a CSS background. I'm guessing at the values below, but you can easily tweak them for your situation.

```
A.aus {
     background-image:url(../images/aus.png);
     background-position:0px 1px;
     display:block;
     height:40px;
     padding-left:60px;
     margin-top:3px;
     font-size:    ....etc.... 
}
```